# Use Intel Pin to instrument Python scripts

Tags: python, c++, instrumentation, intel-pin

I need to instrument a Python script using Intel Pin for [ChampSim](https://github.com/ChampSim/ChampSim) simulator.

The problem is, whenever I run the tool, the script does not seem to run as nothing is printed. Moreover, no matter how long/complex the script is, the trace always ends up with a size of 62M (this is also the case when I simply instrument the interpreter *without* any script).

I tried running the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743298/can-a-pin-tool-instrument-a-bash-script-that-contains-code-to-run-other-commands) post, but it didn't work either. For reference, I am running the following command:

```
../../../pin -t obj-intel64/champsim_tracer.so -- ./python_script.py
```

Is it even possible to instrument a Python script? If yes, please detail the steps. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to instrument a python script, you'll have to instrument the python interpreter (which is where python scripts run), basically `pin -t <pintool> -- python <python_script.py>`. I'm not sure that's exactly what you want. If you just want to see what your python script is executing just use the python profiler.

Comment: I tried that before too, but it didn't work either. I am using Pin to generate a trace for ChampSim simulator.